# Visual Studio Code: prevent it from deleting code that is not needed

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I've noticed that when I add a line that makes the subsequent lines redundant (like a `continue` in a loop, or a `return`), VSCode goes and deletes all subsequent lines - the ones which never run.

As an example, putting the `continue;` line in means the rest is no longer needed and so gets deleted by VSCode:

```
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
   console.log('Loop: ' + i);
   continue;
   var thisWillBeDeleted; // ... but I do not want it to be
}
```

I get it's trying to be helpful and of course in my silly example above, it would be. Is there a way to stop it doing that though? Preferences? Extensions?

There are times when I'll just manually stick a continue in to break a loop to try running it, while debugging, accidentally save, and then have to retrieve all the code it then auto deletes below that line - which I actually *do* want to keep - but it went and got rid of assuming my hack was permanent.

It's not a disaster but gets a bit annoying.

Comment: This is obviously language-specific, so you should add a tag with your language, and tell us if you're using any non-standard extensions for it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks. I didn't know it was. In this case it happens to be JavaScript. I didn't know if it does it with others too. As for extensions, hmm I don't know, have to check. Maybe it will be a case of going down whatever is set up one by one then. Just wondered if anyone else had this happen to them and could say it's a known combination of preference X/extension Y

Comment: you have to look in the formatter that you use, it is not VSC default behavior.

Comment: @rioV8 Ah ok, thanks. I thought it was a new feature as I don't recall it doing that before

Answer (score 3):

Ah ... I eventually figured it out. In case anyone else comes across this, it's the Beautify extension. Maybe it's a feature. Or maybe a conflict with some other combination of extensions. Either way, disable that, problem solved.

Comment: It's not always either the Beautify or Prisma NextJS extensions. I have neither and it is still doing it, and none of my relevant (JS) extensions have this easily visible in their config. What idiot thought this was a good idea?

Comment: @AntonOfTheWoods Ah, interesting. Perhaps _multiple_ extensions do this then. It's apparently not the default. I agree: I don't think they _should_ do that. There are times when you might _want_ redundant lines left in, like while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error similar to yours, I'm just commenting here because I think other devs may bump into this and your answer helped me, but in my case the extension that was f**king up was the [Prisma NextJS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WillLuke.nextjs), after disabling it everything went back to normal.